# Genomic Range Query

Tags: c, complexity, programming-challenge, bioinformatics

Recently I worked on one of the Codility Training - Genomic Range Query (please refer to one of the evaluation report for the detail of [this training](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoYC9TD5-324/)).

The proper approach for this question is using prefix sum. Here is the implementation:

```
struct Results solution(char *S, int P[], int Q[], int M) {
    struct Results result;
    int* ans = (int*)calloc(M, sizeof(int));
    int pre_sum_arr[strlen(S)][4];
    int i, j;

    memset(pre_sum_arr, 0, sizeof(pre_sum_arr));
    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(S) ; i++){
        if(S[i] == 'A') pre_sum_arr[i][0] = 1;
        else if(S[i] == 'C') pre_sum_arr[i][1] = 1;
        else if(S[i] == 'G') pre_sum_arr[i][2] = 1;
        else pre_sum_arr[i][3] = 1;
    }

    for(i = 1; i < strlen(S) ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            pre_sum_arr[i][j] += pre_sum_arr[i - 1][j];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < M ; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            if((P[i] == 0 && pre_sum_arr[Q[i]][j]) || \
               (pre_sum_arr[Q[i]][j] - pre_sum_arr[P[i] - 1][j] > 0)){
                ans[i] = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    result.A = ans;
    result.M = M;
    return result;
}
```

However, the evaluation report said that it exceeds the time limit for large-scale testing case (the report link is above).

The detected time complexity is O(M * N) instead of O(M + N). But in my view, it should be O(M + N) since I ran loop for N and M independently (N for calculating the prefix sum and M for getting the answer).

I also used an alternate solution for this question. I also think its complexity is O(M + N), but I got the same result. Here is my code:

```
struct _pre_min_idx{
  int pre_1_idx;
  int pre_2_idx;
  int pre_3_idx;
};

int mapping(char c){
    if(c == 'A') return 1;
    if(c == 'C') return 2;
    if(c == 'G') return 3;
    if(c == 'T') return 4;
    return -1;
}

typedef struct _pre_min_idx pre_min_idx;

struct Results solution(char *S, int P[], int Q[], int M) {
    struct Results result;
    // A = 1, C = 2, G = 3, T = 4
    pre_min_idx pre_min_idx_arr[strlen(S)];
    int* min_nuc_arr = (int*)calloc(M, sizeof(int));
    int i;
    int pre_1_idx = -1, pre_2_idx = -1, pre_3_idx = -1;

    memset(pre_min_idx_arr, 0, sizeof(pre_min_idx_arr));
    for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(S) ; i++){
        if(S[i] == 'T'){
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_1_idx = pre_1_idx;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_2_idx = pre_2_idx;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_3_idx = pre_3_idx;
        }
        else if(S[i] == 'G'){
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_1_idx = pre_1_idx;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_2_idx = pre_2_idx;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_3_idx = -1;
            pre_3_idx = i;
        }
        else if(S[i] == 'C'){
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_1_idx = pre_1_idx;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_2_idx = -1;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_3_idx = -1;
            pre_2_idx = i;
        }
        else{
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_1_idx = -1;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_2_idx = -1;
            pre_min_idx_arr[i].pre_3_idx = -1;
            pre_1_idx = i;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < M ; i++){
        pre_min_idx pmi_Q = pre_min_idx_arr[Q[i]];
        if(pmi_Q.pre_1_idx >= P[i])
            min_nuc_arr[i] = 1;
        else if(pmi_Q.pre_2_idx >= P[i])
            min_nuc_arr[i] = 2;
        else if(pmi_Q.pre_3_idx >= P[i])
            min_nuc_arr[i] = 3;
        else{
            min_nuc_arr[i] = mapping(S[Q[i]]);
        }
    }
    result.A = min_nuc_arr;
    result.M = M;
    return result;
}
```

The evaluation report is [here](https://codility.com/demo/results/demoKYT9PV-FVP/).

Could anyone help me to figure out what the problem is for my solution? I get stuck for long time. Any performance improvement trick or advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strlen` takes a linear time in the length of the string. Thus, `for(i = 0 ; i < strlen(S) ; i++)` will call it `n` times and the result will be quadratic.

Changing this and a few other details (moving stuff to the smallest possible scope) and you get this :

```
struct Results solution(char *S, int P[], int Q[], int M) {
    int len = strlen(S);
    int pre_sum_arr[len][4];

    memset(pre_sum_arr, 0, sizeof(pre_sum_arr));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
             if(S[i] == 'A') pre_sum_arr[i][0] = 1;
        else if(S[i] == 'C') pre_sum_arr[i][1] = 1;
        else if(S[i] == 'G') pre_sum_arr[i][2] = 1;
        else                 pre_sum_arr[i][3] = 1;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < len; i++){
        for(j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            pre_sum_arr[i][j] += pre_sum_arr[i - 1][j];
        }
    }

    int* ans = (int*)calloc(M, sizeof(int));
    for(int i = 0 ; i < M ; i++){
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 4 ; j++){
            if((P[i] == 0 && pre_sum_arr[Q[i]][j]) || \
               (pre_sum_arr[Q[i]][j] - pre_sum_arr[P[i] - 1][j] > 0)){
                ans[i] = j + 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    struct Results result;
    result.A = ans;
    result.M = M;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Josay, thank you for pointing out where I missed, it helps a lot. Such a silly mistake I made :/

Comment: Might be dodgy putting  int pre_sum_arr[len][4]; on the stack, if len is huge.

Answer (score 5):

Just a few notes not mentioned in other answers:

- You can `typedef` your `struct` right away.

  ```
  typedef struct
  {
      int pre_1_idx;
      int pre_2_idx;
      int pre_3_idx;
  } PreMinIdx;
  ```

  Then initialize it with a more unique name.

  ```
  PreMinIdx UniqueName;
  ```
- Use `else if`s in your `mapping()` method.  And since you aren't modifying the function parameter, declare it as `const` (as you should do with all function parameters you don't modify within the function).

  ```
  int mapping(const char c)
  {
      if (c == 'A') return 1;
      else if (c == 'C') return 2;
      else if (c == 'G') return 3;
      else if (c == 'T') return 4;
      else return -1;
  }
  ```
- Some of your variable name do not follow the standard naming conventions of beginning with a lowercase letter, and they aren't very descriptive.

  > ```
  > char *S, int P[], int Q[], int M
  > ```

  Even short names such as `str` would be more descriptive.
- Declare `i` inside of your `for` loops.<sup>(C99)</sup>

  ```
  for(int i = 0; i < strlen(S); i++)
  ```